# WPF Menu on Winforms

Tags: wpf, winforms, winforms-interop

Is it possible to show WPF Context menu on WinForms?

If yes, how could we do that?

Comment: why don't you show WinForms context menus on your WinForms app?

Comment: Because I have a form in my app done in Winform ages ago, but all new implementation is in WPF, so I'm wondering whether I can reuse existing context menu

Answer (score 3):

OK, so I've found the answer myself... (I tried to give a 50 point bounty, but I don't think I can award myself :P)

We have a lot of legacy WinForms... forms... still in our project at work. And here's the secret code that is needed to display a WPF Context Menu in a WinForms project!

```
var myMenu = new System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenu();
myMenu.Items.Add("One");
myMenu.Items.Add("Two");
myMenu.Items.Add("Three");
myMenu.IsOpen = true;
```

Tada!!! - There is no secret code needed... you can write this code in a WPF App or a WinForms app and it works the same.

And there's your answer :)

Comment: Get out of town, I was able to award myself!

Answer (score 2):

You can mix the 2 technologies using `WindowsFormsHost` (WinForm inside WPF window) and `ElementHost` (WPF inside WinForm window).

You will not encounter the [Airspace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970688%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) issue as you are adding a WPF menu into a Winform application. But you will if you create WPF windows with Winform UserControls. This [Blog post](http://jmorrill.hjtcentral.com/Home/tabid/428/EntryId/61/Over-coming-the-Interop-Airspace-Issue-in-WPF.aspx) has some ideas about solving it, but it is not pretty.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it can be done, but [this article](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-using-wpf-in-winforms) might help point you in the right direction.  As a WPF developer, it seems strange to me to want to mix winforms and wpf, but i can see the case for re-use.